# Blender Game Engine: Do something when an 'action' animation happens

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

For a game I'm making, I need to make a sensor be positive every time an 'action' animation runs.
This is my shooting setup:[image: logic]

So how do I check what frame an action is at? Because if this is possible I can make a python script so that when the animation is at frame 1 it does something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property (float or int) and enter it into the Frame Property field (right lower corner of your image). Then you can check the property with a property sensor.

**Be aware** that frames are float. Therefore it is better to check against a range e.g. 0.5 ... 1.5 (Interval mode) rather than a concrete value, as it is not likely to match it.

[image]

Comment: It works! I also find it works better if I make the frame property an integer